# More than one value in ado power-shell task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am writing pipeline code inazure devops where i need to read names from a file using powershell and pass on to another task in same pipeline. Please help

```
task: PowerShel1@2 
inputs:
targetType: 'inline" 
script:
    $file_data = Get-Content   test.yml | Where-Object ($_
-like ‘tableId’)
     Write-Host "$file _data"
     $tableid- ($file data -split 'r?\n')
      #Write-Host length Stableid.Length

      for ($i= 0; $i- It $tableid.Length $i++)
{

      #Write-Host $tableid[$i].length
      if ($tableid[$i] -ne "tabIeId:”)
      #Write-Host insideIF
        $position -      $tableid[$i].Indexof (" :")
      Write-Output $tableid[$i].Substring($position+1)
Write-Host
       "##vso [task.setvariable variable=out1]stablei


- script:echo $ (out1)
```

In above script i get more than one tableId name and i want to output those values to another task

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not clear in your example... but.. I think, you can:

1. join your values into one variable in the for cycle:

   ```
   $name = $tableid[$i].Substring($position+1)
   $myoutput += "$name;"
   ```
2. After for, pass it to the pipeline variable

   ```
   Write-Host "##vso [task.setvariable variable=out1]$myoutput"
   ```
3. Then split the pipeline variable in the next step

   ```
   $names = "$(out1)" -split ";"
   ```

Comment: Thank you Shamrai, when iam splitting getting error .

Comment: -script: |   $names = “$(out1)” -split “;”

Comment: @ChavaVenkat this task should be Powershell inline... not a script....

Comment: Got it, it worked in powershell.

Comment: @ChavaVenkat mark as an answer... maybe someone also will find this post useful

Comment: one last  error before mark it as answer..

Comment: - powershell: | $Data = “(out1)”.split(“;”)     Write-Output “##vso[task.setvariable variable=tnames]$Data -${{each tbname in $tbnames}}: -script : | gcloud bigtable instances tables create $tbname.  This code is saying “Unrecognized value: ‘$tbnames’”. Please help how can i pass poweshell variable to for each to other task

Comment: @ChavaVenkat 1) here is a simple mistake between `task.setvariable variable=tnames` and `${{each tbname in $tbnames}}`... just add or remove `b`. 2) however you can not pass arrays as variables, you can use strings only because this is an environment variable ... so in your script, you have to split a string and then run some processing application

Comment: if i cant pass array then i wont be able to loop thru it. If you see at my second script where iam creating table using gcloud, i want loop thru the list of table names and create those many tables